# Redirecting https site to http url in Nginx

Tags: nginx

I have this redirect script in my nginx.conf file. I want to redirect to http:// site but my origin is https:// how do I remove the 's' from the url? Adding the http:// to the pass won't work

```
rewrite ^(?!/mt/)(.*)$ /content$1 break;
```

Origin: `https://blog.com/mt/content/apple/site.php`

Redirect: `http://blog.com/content/apple/site.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use protocol and host in redirect:

```
rewrite ^(?!/mt/)(.*)$ http://blog.com/content$1 break;
```